# The calling thread cannot access the object-RunWorkerCompleted event in backgroundWorker c#

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

The exception message stated above occurs generally when UI controls are accessed by other threads rather than the UI thread itself.I came through this issue.As far my experience,i faced this error while i tried to access the UI from a `BackGroundWorker`'s `DoWork` event.When i became aware of the fact that the UI cannot be accessed from a different thread rather than the UI thread,i switched to other methods to tackle such a situation by doing some HEAVY NON-UI work in `DoWork` event.Today,i thought of doing something different(which may be not different to u as u may have done this before).I tried to do the UI THINGS in `DoWork` event in a very different way.

Before i post my huge code,excuse me to explain a bit please.

My motive was to load a few images in some `Image` control from a database/datatable in **WPF**.This takes some time as there are more than just a few images in the database/datatable.It results in **UI-Freeze**.So i though if declaring a **Class level `List(of BitmapImage)` variable**,add images to that and then , in `RunWorkerCompleted` event,i thought of doing a `For Each` loop and load images in `Image` controls.

Before i would test it, i tried implementing this using a database with single image and only a single `Image` control.

Here's how i add images:

```
public class TestSub
{
BitmapImage CurrentUserPhoto = new BitmapImage;
private void LoadAccounts_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select * from userinfo where   Email='" + currentemail + "'", con);
    byte[] photo;
    OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader;
    while (dr2.Read)
    {
        try
        {
            photo = (byte[])dr2(11);
            MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(photo);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage;
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bi.StreamSource = strm;
            bi.EndInit();
            CurrentUserPhoto = bi;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        if (dr2(9).ToString == "")
        {
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentUser = dr2(9);
        }
    }

    con.Close();
}
}
```

Then,in `RunWorkerCompleted`, i try to load that image :

```
 private void LoadCurrentAccount_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    CurrentUserPhoto.BeginInit();
    userpic.ImageSource = CurrentUserPhoto;
    CurrentUserPhoto.EndInit();
    CurrentUserName.Content = CurrentUser;
}
```

BAMMM!The error occurs!! In the first line `CurrentUserPhoto.BeginInit();` . I am not getting it as i am(as far my knowledge) not tying to access the UI from a different thread(i mean,i ain't accessing it from `DoWordk` event).

So,can somebody please explain to me why this error is occuring ?

Comment: The content in `CurrentUserPhoto` is still created in a background thread. The place of assignments is less important.

Comment: what to do then ?

Comment: Get the byte array in the background and create the image itself in the completed event.

Comment: No, don't do that! Just call `bi.Freeze()` after EndInit to make it cross-thread accessible. And as a general rule, close the MemoryStream by a using block `using (var str = new MemoryStream(photo)) { ... }`

Comment: @Clemens ah, didn't know. Thanks, learnt something new today!

Comment: i will try but @PeterBons, can u explain a bit

Comment: @Clemens,it now throws `Specified value of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' must have IsFrozen set to false to modify`

Comment: Sure, after freezing it can't be modified. No idea what you're doing though... However, `CurrentUserPhoto.BeginInit()` and `CurrentUserPhoto.EndInit()` in RunWorkerCompleted don't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @clemens,i tried to add the bitmap from `DoWork` to `currentUserPhoto` and wanted to uses as the imagesource of `UserPic`, and i know that `beginInIt` and `EndInIt` is useless in `RunWorkerCompleted` event but if i remove 'em , i get an error which suggests to add them...any help with that ?

Comment: @Clemens,thank u sooo much!! I understood and solved my problem.